# Little (Employee - Shift) SQL Database help

Tags: sql, timetable

Im creating a little database that has employee, emp_shift, shift, tables
now im suppose to be able to calculate at the end of the month which employee
has done the most number of shifts.

Ive created the SQL creation, insert statements for the tables, and a little diagram to explain what im trying to acomplish, im a beginner and this is a homework ive been trying to do for the last 4 days.

Diagram: http://latinunit.net/emp_shift.jpg
SQL: http://latinunit.net/emp_shift.txt

can you please guys check it, deadline is 2 days and this is just a part of the whole database

Comment: It's hard to check if you don't link to the SQL file.

Comment: Kind of a funny typo in Table Shift constraints...  Also, your PK in the EMP_SHIT table won't work.  It will only allow employees to work each shift once in their entire lives.  The date should also be part of the key.  Timestamp fields could be varchars, because you don't really care about them.  They are basically descriptions and it appears you won't do math on them.

Comment: But emp_shift is a composite entity, because there is a many to many relationship between employee and shift so each primary key of each table will be used in the composite entity as primary keys. this is what ive been taught, but then maybe we can make the date_shift attribute to be part of the whole key also?

CONSTRAINT EMP_SHIFT_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID, SHIFT_ID, EMP_SHIFT_DATE),

Comment: Yes, that is what I was saying.  The way you wrote it initially since those 2 cols were the only ones in the PK, employees would be prevented from having 2 records in that table.  With respect to what you learned -- you have to use the PK of the two parent tables, but you will also have to add another column to they key in order to make it work.

Comment: thanks from what u taught me it helped me fixed loads of contraints in my database

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Keep asking questions, and keep providing enough info for people to answer them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a reasonable start.  Will you have more tables?  If not, it will be hard to identify how to pay people -- for example, it seems that you might want a "pay-period" table.  Then you could find the start and end dates and be able to count the shifts within that period.

But if all you need to do is exactly what you said, that is a fair start.

(I am assuming you have other columns in mind, such as employee name, but that would be obvious).

Comment: BTW, since this seems to be your second in what will be a series of questions, you should ACCEPT an answer to the first question.  It appears you got your table definition from the answer there.  If you liked it and used it, just ACCEPT it already.  See my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

*You could start by telling us whoch RDBMS you are using, as some of the finer details might be different between RDMSs.*

You need to create a link between tables (Called JOINS, [Read this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)) and then perform a [count](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) of the requested data.

After you have read some of these, show us what you have done, and we can help you where you are having trouble.

Comment: im using oracle i dont think it has datetime

Answer (score 0):

also, it would be better practive to use a single numeric as the primary key instead of 'A', 'B', 'C' etc.